# Database structure - Multiple users

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to MySQL and just wondering how do I structure my data base for a user who will have a message board (Private), user info (Private), and a blog info(also private). Everything on the database will be private.

Should I create a database for each user (can I)? Or, a table for the message board, user info and blog info. Or maybe your own opinion would be great!

I'm trying to create a personal Wed Diary.

Comment: just tag all of the info with the specific user identifier, and you would handle access to that data at the application level, by making sure the user identifier of any retrieved data matches the user identifier of the logged in user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should *not* create a separate database or table for each user -- unless some arcane requirement gives you no choice.

Instead, just include the user who created each object in the table.  For instance, the blog info table would have the user id who created it.  Then all queries on it would include:

```
from blogInfo bi
where bi.userId = $userId -- or something similar
```